# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: parsing, parse-error, php-parse-error

Was trying to install a wp plugin- dt world clock and got this error msg.

The actual error msg:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/dt-world-clock/dt-world-clock.php on line 415

And the line 415 is:

`function DT_World_Clock_Shortcode($atts = [], $content = null, $tag = '') {`

I have no idea where to edit-

Would really appreciate help...

Answer (score 0):

try this
function DT_World_Clock_Shortcode($atts = array(), $content = null, $tag = "") {